# SQLCipher createTable

Tags: sqlite, ormlite, sqlcipher

How can I copy/implement the `SQLite.CreateTable<T>`, `SQLite.DropTable<T>` and other methods like these into SQLCipher? I use SQLCipher in Xamarin with a binded Java library.

So there is any solution to use the ORM database schemes in SQLCipher?

Answer (score 0):

You might find the [Getting Started](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sqlcipher-for-xamarin-android) documentation helpful. If you have more specific questions, SQLCipher has its own [discuss](https://discuss.zetetic.net/c/sqlcipher) site.

Comment: My IDE can't find `SQLitePlatformAndroid` class. I didn't purchased the library which you linked in. I just downloaded the open source Android library and created a binding library.